# Is there an online license statement for OpenCV where I can point to?

Tags: opencv

I used the OpenCV library in my Android application. I know it is BSD license and I wish to put a link to the license statement in my 'About' page.

However I failed to find the license statement within the official page itself (http://opencv.org/) and Google.. I can only find old statements in someone else's website.

Just wondering if there is an online official version where my app can point to, such as the one below:
http://scorpion.tordivel.no/help/GettingStarted/OpenCVLicence.htm

Thanks!

Comment: There maybe an official license document in the download of the library, but it seems to be available in the source code repo, https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/doc/license.txt

Comment: That is just what I'm looking for.. thanks! If you can convert your comment to an actual answer though I could mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312308/opencv-for-commercial-use), OpenCV is [BSD 3-Clause License](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause).

The text you are searching for actually really is not on the homepage.
You can find the licence.txt in the project download package in the doc directory though.